# Is it possible to find my first programmer/reverse-engineer job abroad?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, ethics, qualification, russia

First off, I am living in 3rd-world country which I want to leave in future. I plan on working as programmer or software reverse-engineer to get more experience and start seeking job vacancies abroad. I ask it because I doubt it is possible that a foreign employer deems profitable accepting novice programmer/reverse-engineer.

Also, most employers for reverse-engineering positions in my country seem to collaborate with government, which is not good at all. I don't want to realize I am a part of organization that helps someone do, or try to do, **a lot** of bad things in the world(reverse-engineering skills can be used to produce malware).

Can I have a chance if I have some complex projects, or experience of working at remote job?

Comment: _"I reside in Russia."_ & _"First off, I am living in 3rd-world country"_ Not trying to be a nitpick - but Russia is considerd a 2nd world country in the eyes of the western 1st world countries and might be considered as 1st world country by some 3rd world countries or transitionals..

Answer (score 5):

Your concerns seem valid. Yes, it's generally difficult to get hired remotely as a novice. There's not much that can be said there except to try and push your luck; and get experience and certification wherever you can. If you consider it undesirable to work in that particular domain in your country, work in a different but related domain, or study in that domain to get degrees or certifications demonstrating expertise.

### Visa requirements

Howver, there's another issue - you haven't indicated your country, but it might be even more important/restricting than your maing question. Regardless of whether employers would want to hire you, you'd also need to verify whether they *could* hire you.

It depends a lot on the particular countries and what citizenship you have, but in general for many/most third world countries getting a first world visa that allows you to be employed is not trivial, especially if you're a novice - the process for visas like H1-B and similar in other countries is intended to cover only qualified specialists, so you/the employer may have to show that you're *not* a novice, otherwise they might not be permitted to hire you.

Comment: I reside in Russia. How does it influence whether I can be proposed job offer?

Comment: @M.Kalter if you're a Russian citizen then as far as I understand in most first world countries the default position is that you'll be welcome as a tourist but will *not* be granted a visa that permits employment, unless you fulfil the criteria of some 'highly skilled migrants' scheme which most such countries have, and likely you need a "sponsoring" job offer before applying for that visa. It's certainly possible to do, many Russian engineers have done so, but it's not trivial and needs careful attention to the specific requirements (which will vary for different countries) and some planning.

Comment: @M.Kalter that being said, in similar situations it's common to get a visa for studies, which tend to be easier to get and may allow some employment to cover expenses, and enable some transition to a work visa after getting more degrees/certification.